# Can anyone please explain to me the concept of partitioned hive tables?

Tags: hiveql

Can anyone explain the point of partitioning a Hive table.

If I create a table and partition it by date. In hdfs it is shown as a file name.. or a sub file. What does this mean?

Can anyone please explain the concept ?

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded one partition, namely the "age equals 22" partition with your entire data set.  Therefore, all rows in your table have an age of 22.

If you specify a partition in your statement, it will write into that partition. You might be wanting dynamic partitions where you can create partitions pulled from some select statement.

In general, the purpose of partitioning in Hive is to improve performance and to structure the table to mirror know access patterns and usage - eg I always query my table by age.